# How to create a WordPress website when the hosting service doesn't include a CPanel or a remote access to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, web, hosting

How to create a WordPress website when the hosting package that was given by T-Home (T-Mobile) only includes a FTP password and FTP username, but doesn't include an access to a hosting panel or a remote access to MySQL?

Comment: hmmm check if you can connect to the FTP by installing filezilla or winsCP

Answer (score 0):

If you've been provided a MySQL database, but you just can't access it remotely then this shouldn't be a problem. You can just upload the Wordpress installation files via FTP and then open your website in your browser and you can configure everything with the WordPress installation wizard, which should automatically start once you uploaded everything to your webspace.

If your provider hasn't provided you a MySQL database I see no way to make this work. (You can create a Blog on http://wordpress.com though).

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.

- You can download WordPress installation zip in your local system, extract it and upload it on server using FTP account.
- MySQL is generally installed in same server and you can use localhost as server name (no need to have remote access). Most of the providers do not provide remote mysql access to avoid security issues.
- Once you have uploaded WordPress files on server, access your site with domain.com (if the domain is pointing to same server) OR if it does not point to server, you can access it with temporary URL and proceed with the installation steps.